# Please Help Me Understand This ( From 3Blue1Brown Video about Taylor Series)

Tags: proof-explanation, taylor-expansion

[image: This is the screenshot that i took from the video]

at that point in the video he said the height of the triangle is equal to the slope times (x - a), but i failed to understand how. shouldn't the height be found using pythagoras theorem ? how can height = (slope)(x-a) ?

Thanks in advance
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Slope is rise over run. If the slope of a line is $4$, let’s say, then when you move one unit to the right you move $4$ units up. When you move $h$ units to the right you move $4h$ units up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, by the definition of slope, the slope is equal to the height of triangle divided by $x-a$.

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.